# R change column names over multiple data

Tags: r, function, names

I'm trying to change column names over multiple data sets. I have tried writing the following function to do this:

```
# simplified test data #
df1<-as.data.frame(c("M","F"))
colnames(df1)<-"M1"

# my function #
rename_cols<-function(df){
  colnames(df)[names(df) == "M1"] <- "sex"
}
rename_cols(df1)
```

However when testing this function on df1, the column is always called "M1" instead of "sex". How can I correct this?

SOLUTION - THANKS TO DAVID ARENBERG

```
rename_cols<-function(df){
  colnames(df)[names(df) == "M1"] <- "sex"
  df
}
df1<-rename_cols(df1)
```

Comment: Have you tried something to the tone of `names(df1)[grepl("M1", names(df1)] <- "sex"`? This will find which column name is "M1" and replace it with "sex".

Comment: Functions are operating in a temporary environment. Your code works, but on a temporary data set which then vanishes. If you want to return a data set with renamed column names you need to add additional line within your function that will have `df` in it (which means that you want the function to give you the temporary data set back instead of erasing it on exit). Though it still will create a copy and won't modify your original data set. I wonder though, how you want to run this function on multiple data sets. Can you provide a more general example and desired output?

Comment: Roman - this is an alternative but remains in the temporary environment. David - Thankyou, I have added this above.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which gets around the problem of functions operating in a temporary space:

```
df <- as.data.frame(c("M","F"))
colnames(df) <- "M1"

rename_cols <- function(df) {
    colnames(df)[names(df) == "M1"] <<- "sex"
}

> rename_cols(df)         # this will operate directly on the 'df' object
> df
  sex
1   M
2   F
```

Using the global assignment operator `<<-` makes the name changes to the input data frame `df` "stick".  Granted, this solution is not ideal because it means the function could potentially do something unwanted.  But I feel this is in the spirit of what you were trying to do originally.

Comment: @DavidArenburg Please review this answer and let us know what you think.

Comment: Not sure... I wouldn't do it this way, but I guess it's up to you/OP